# Write from an Azure Container Instance to a blob storage inside a managed vnet

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

I use a Synapse Analytics resource on azure with a managed virtual network. It uses a storage account with the same vnet created automatically by Synapse.
I want to deploy an azure container instance with a java program which uses azure-spring-boot-starter-storage to write into it.

How can I authorize my container to write to the storage ?

I'm not sure I can put the container inside the vnet since it was automatically created and I do not see it in the portal.

Do I need to create a private endpoint ? How to create it since I can't select the vnet in the portal ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   I tried to create a private endpoint in my Azure Synapse analytics workspace by selecting the resource type as **‘Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters’** and selecting the intended **Azure Kubernetes Services cluster** but couldn’t find any provision to select an **ACI** in there. So, if you have any ACI deployed, then you would not be able to select the ACI but if you deployed your java program in an AKS cluster, then you have the option of selecting it and configuring the managed virtual network created when deploying an Azure Synapse workspace for the private endpoint with that AKS cluster.

•   Also, you can configure the private endpoint in the following way as shown in the screenshot below: -

[image: AKS cluster selection]
[image: Private endpoint]

You can also configure the storage account in the AKS cluster to the same container in which **Data lake storage Generation 2** account is created for the Azure Synapse workspace so that the java program which uses the ‘Azure-Spring-boot-starter-storage’ can write in the same storage account container or different custom container.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed created a private endpoint